# MatLAB: Limiting Intensity Values of an Image

Tags: matlab

I have about 200 CT scans that I need to limit their intensity values between -2048 and 2048. I tried histeq and imadjust but they did not work. I get the best result when I use imshow(image, [-2048,2048]). But I need to save the result data of this `imshow`.

[`imshow` result without display range](http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/268/39979786.jpg)

[`imshow` result with display range](http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/3909/76610719.jpg)

I want to obtain the output image of imshow with display range and to be able to save it?

Best

Comment: what is the range of your input CT scans? Can you provide the exact code you tried for `histeq` and `imadjust`? Why were you not happy with these results? **How exactly do you display negative intensities in `imshow`**?

Comment: @Shai: `imshow` maps the intensites onto the colormap from the minimum range to the maximum range - in the present case, -2048 corresponds to black, 2048 corresponds to white with the limits set.

Comment: For data that are not in standard grayscale or RGB you can use imagesc() for displaying it.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is limit the range of the values the same way `imshow` does it, you can write

```
limits = [-2048 2048];
limitedImage = min(max(originalImage, limits(1)), limits(2));
```

This will set all intensities lower than -2048 to -2048, and all intensities above 2048 to 2048.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jonas suggested, you may want to truncate extreme values.
Alternately you can rescale your colors to make sure you always make full use of the entire spectrum (with maximum contrast).

```
scaledImage = zeros(size(originalImage)) % Just for initialization
desiredRange = 2*2048;
currentRange = max(originalImage(:)) - min(originalImage(:)); % You will want to remove NaNs first if they occur
currentMean = mean(originalImage(:))
scaledImage(:) = currentMean + (originalImage(:) - currentMean) * desiredRange /currentRange
```

This will set all intensities lower than -2048 to -2048, and all intensities above 2048 to 2048.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use some function that is limited and monotone.

eg. I would use something like `limitedImage = 2048*tanh(originalImage/2048)`

Using this you could recover the original image, and wouldn't loose the information for values over 2048.